# How to edit the internal webpage of router using Upload/Download?

Tags: networking, router, modem, dsl-modem

I have a Beetel 450TC1 Router (with WiFi).

I would like to know if there's any way out if I could tweak the web interface of the router by editing the internal webpages stored in it or connecting to it with FTP.

I searched all over the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Its very unlikely you will be able to do this.  Most consumer routers use a locked down firmware.  Why exactly do you want to modify the web interface.  Your best bet would be to find a third-party firmware that is capatible with your router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A router usually has internal flash to store its firmware and limited memory. Thus the webpages you see are almost guaranteed to be stored in the flash.

To change them you need to:

1. Get a copy of the current firmware.
2. Unpack it so that you can edit it.
3. Edit it
4. Repack it as firmware.
5. Flash the modem with the new firmware and hope you did not make any errors. If you made an error you might have just bricked your Beetel.

So, the practical answer is: No, you can not just edit them.

You can look if there is a firmware available for your device which allows you do make easier changes (See a list of those [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wireless_router_firmware_projects)). Howevereven with a relative open firmware changing the webpage layout is non-trivial.

Comment: And obviously there might be a possible workaround...

Comment: Well, you could write a new firmware, somehow add the manufacturers validation codes and physically change the chip on the router. But that seems a lot of effort. Almost the same for using JTAG. Replacing the original firmware with a more open one from the list in my post would be a lot safer and a lot less work.

Answer (score 2):

The "webpages" in a router aren't stored on a drive on the router that you can edit. They are stored in firmware. You can attempt to modify that firmware, but it's not a scripting job like a website edit. It would be extremely difficult (for someone without prior experience doing it), and if a mistake was made, you would permanently brick the router.

A better option would be using a custom firmware such as [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) or [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato).

Comment: And the same as @Ramhound :)

Comment: Tomato or DD-WRT aren't available for my router (incompatible !).
If by I could get more information on unpacking and editing the firmware, that would be nice. `Firmware Version : TM4-0Q-008`.

Comment: @KunalGupta You would have to get the validation codes from the manufacturer, which I have no idea where you would get those. You're asking for us to provide with easy steps to do something that requires a few college courses to explain.

Comment: Just asking: the firmware update uses .ras files... If I could get some possible hints on how to deal with the unpacking and coding or which software to be used that would be nice:-) . Also as I checked the internet, I was surprised to see that no one had thought of such manual operations on their router instead of using a custom firmware like Tomato or DD-WRT.

Comment: @KunalGupta Have you considered that creating a custom firmware like these companies have done **are** a manual operation as you're suggesting? You're trying to accomplish what they've already done with teams of experts. What you're trying to do is not something someone can you give you step by step instructions for. It is an extremely lengthy, difficult, and complicated process that can't be boiled down or simplified.

Comment: @Moses I know that; I was just asking for a hint. I know it's a tedious job and I didn't mean to say that any amateur could do it. All I asked for was a hint. It's OK if you are not able to provide one :)

Comment: @KunalGupta If anyone knew any more information about how to do this, it would have already been posted. You may get better answers from the developers of third-party firmware.